# ERR This instance has cluster support disabled

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, redis

I am trying to connect to cluster Redis with a valid URL and port I got this error:

```
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: ERR This instance has cluster support disabled
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:135)
    at io.lettuce.core.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:108)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.completeResult(AsyncCommand.java:118)
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.AsyncCommand.complete(AsyncCommand.java:109)
```

I have `cluster-enabled yes`

Comment: Hi! Do you have any update on this? How did you resolve this? @yali

Comment: @OsamaKhalid I just added the cluster url not sample redis

Comment: @yali could you elaborate? What do you mean by "added the cluster url"? Where did you add it?

Answer (score 1):

(yeah, this is an old question)

This is typically a result of an attempt to connect using cluster mode to a standalone server (started as a container for development?). IOW, in the code you probably have:

```java
Config config = new Config();
config.useClusterServers() // <<--- Cluster mode
      .addNodeAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:7000");
```

but should be:

```java
Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer() // <<-- Single node mode
      .setAddress("redis://127.0.0.1:7000");
```

See: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/2.-Configuration/#26-single-instance-mode

Comment: what if java old hairy non-maintainable part of the equation... No way to mimic a cluster by a single instance/container?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the conf as an argument

```
redis-server redis.conf
```